System not able to boot
I recently installed Arch Linux, and when I ran efibootmgr from the installation medium’s live CD, the output was:
Boot0001* GRUB HD(2,GPT,7fd0185c-03b8-492b-b07d-9b64e4f23b6d,0x200800,0x100000)/\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi
However, when I exit the installation medium and attempt to boot the system, selecting the boot entry just takes me back to the boot menu. After re-entering the installation medium and checking efibootmgr again, the output changes to:
Boot0025* UEFI SOLIDIGM SSDPFKKW020X7, Partition 2 PciRoot(0x0)/xxxxxxx
(x indicates several more characters and /\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi is missing from the tail)
I am using the Gigabyte MS03-6L0, and there are no settings related to CSM/UEFI in the BIOS. Secure boot is also disabled.
How should I resolve this issue?
I tried running grub-install and grub-mkconfig several times to rebuild my boot entries, but as soon as I exit the installation medium and reboot, the issue reoccurs.

The official OS support list doesn't mention Arch but it should work anyway. Do you have a correct ESP? Was the bootloader (GRUB) correctly installed? Have you checked UEFI settings - Boot menu - OS selection (or similar wording) making sure an entry explicitly saying "ArchLinux" is selected (if more than one - likely from previous unsuccessful attempts - try all)?
